# How to write a consolePatternMatchListener extension point?

Tags: scala, eclipse-plugin, console

I am running an external tool from a scala plug-in project. The tool might generate errors/warnings on certain conditions, which I would like to make clickable, to be able to jump to point of occurence. The error is message is of following syntax:

```
<absolute_file_path>:<line_no>:ERROR: <message>
```

I searched and understood that a consolePatternMatchListener extension point needs to be added and got the following example:

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePatternMatchListeners">
      <consolePatternMatchListener
            class="com.example.ExampleConsolePatternMatcher"
            id="com.example.ExampleConsolePatternMatcher"
            regex=".*foo.*">
         <enablement>
            <test property="org.eclipse.ui.console.consoleTypeTest" value="exampleConsole"/>
         </enablement>
      </consolePatternMatchListener>
   </extension>
```

Since I am very new to eclipse plugin development, I wanted to know how to go about writing the above extension in plugin.xml->Extension Point

Answer (score 0):

You might find this tutorial useful: [Eclipse Extension Points and Extensions](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html)